# Pandas must label all objects otherwise legend wrong?

Tags: python, pandas, legend

picture and code from
https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/exponential_smoothing.html#Exponential-smoothing

Problems appear when I want to show legends by Pandas, I can't show some of them, or legend's color will wrong.

In section 'Simple Exponential Smoothing'

```py
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.tsa.api import ExponentialSmoothing, SimpleExpSmoothing, Holt

data = [446.6565,  454.4733,  455.663 ,  423.6322,  456.2713,  440.5881, 425.3325,  485.1494,  506.0482,  526.792 ,  514.2689,  494.211 ]
index= pd.date_range(start='1996', end='2008', freq='A')
oildata = pd.Series(data, index)

ax=oildata.plot()
ax.set_xlabel("Year")
ax.set_ylabel("Oil (millions of tonnes)")
plt.show()
print("Figure 7.1: Oil production in Saudi Arabia from 1996 to 2007.")

fit1 = SimpleExpSmoothing(oildata).fit(smoothing_level=0.2,optimized=False)
fcast1 = fit1.forecast(3).rename(r'$\alpha=0.2$')
fit2 = SimpleExpSmoothing(oildata).fit(smoothing_level=0.6,optimized=False)
fcast2 = fit2.forecast(3).rename(r'$\alpha=0.6$')
fit3 = SimpleExpSmoothing(oildata).fit()
fcast3 = fit3.forecast(3).rename(r'$\alpha=%s$'%fit3.model.params['smoothing_level'])

ax = oildata.plot(marker='o', color='black', figsize=(12,8))
fcast1.plot(marker='o', ax=ax, color='blue', legend=True)
fit1.fittedvalues.plot(marker='o', ax=ax, color='blue')
fcast2.plot(marker='o', ax=ax, color='red', legend=True)
fit2.fittedvalues.plot(marker='o', ax=ax, color='red')
fcast3.plot(marker='o', ax=ax, color='green', legend=True)
fit3.fittedvalues.plot(marker='o', ax=ax, color='green')
plt.show()
```

[result picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjCpO.png)

notice that the color of legends are wrong

But if I change fit1,2 and 3 like this:

```py
...
fit1.fittedvalues.plot(marker='o', ax=ax, color='blue',legend=True)#to make every line legend True
fcast2.plot(marker='o', ax=ax, color='red', legend=True)
...
```

New legend will run well.(except the same color of two legends)

So question is, if I want to show legend of Pandas plot, I must make all lines (or objects) legend is True so that the color could be right?

Dose it exist some ways can I show some legends and make others invisible?

Answer (score 0):

One way: Put all objects that need to legend before showing other objects

```py
fcast1.plot(marker='o', ax=ax, color='blue', legend=True)
fcast2.plot(marker='o', ax=ax, color='red', legend=True)
fcast3.plot(marker='o', ax=ax, color='green', legend=True)
fit1.fittedvalues.plot(marker='o', ax=ax, color='blue')
fit2.fittedvalues.plot(marker='o', ax=ax, color='red')
fit3.fittedvalues.plot(marker='o', ax=ax, color='green')
```